# wordpress add multiple callback function to single ajax action from different plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I was trying to add one more callback function to wordpress ajax action

```
woocommerce_apply_coupon
```

this wp_ajax action is defined in woocommerce plugin,I want to add my own callback function on this action from my plugin file .

what i have tried -

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_apply_coupon','darn',999);
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'darn',999);

function darn(){
         print_r($_REQUEST);
         exit;
    }
```

Doing this in my functions.php is not even showing any error, like i cant see any effect of this code.

want to know if this  is even  possible to achieve . Thankyou.

Comment: How do you enable Ajaxified coupons? I cannot seem to find the option. Is it made available by the theme?

Comment: it has nothing to do with theme, coupons are applied via ajax on checkout page. have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i would like to answer my own question since nobody seems to answer it .

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_apply_coupon','darn',1);
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'darn',1);

function darn(){
         print_r($_REQUEST);
         exit;
    }
```

by setting priority to one (giving my callback function the top priority) it actually worked !

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I'd try to solve it removing the original actions *after* all plugins are loaded, and then adding your substitute:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'b5f_new_ajax_coupon', 15 );

function b5f_new_ajax_coupon() 
{
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'woocommerce_ajax_apply_coupon' );
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'woocommerce_ajax_apply_coupon' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'b5f_ajax_apply_coupon' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'b5f_ajax_apply_coupon' );
}   

function b5f_ajax_apply_coupon()
{
    // COPY THE ORIGINAL /woocommerce/woocommerce-ajax.php#L57
    // AND ADAPT TO YOUR NEEDS
}
```

Comment: i have resolved this issue, thankyou for your help though :) it was priority which was bugging me !